# xsl : how to translate or replace string?

Tags: xml, string, xslt, replace, translate

my xsl variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="string">Satur - Sun - Mon - Tues - Wednes - Thurs - Fri</xsl:variable>
```

i need to translate or replace the `string` variable data from:

```
Satur - Sun - Mon - Tues - Wednes - Thurs - Fri
```

**so, the output should be like this:**

```
Saturday - Sunday - Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday
```

................................

@Mads Hansen
i am newbie in `xsl` and `xml` and i tried your code but it not works
`100%` it is wrong

**my xsl file:**

```
    <xsl:variable name="string">Satur - Sun - Mon - Tues - Wednes - Thurs - Fri</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>result: </h2>
                <xsl:value-of 
                    select="for $token in tokenize($string, '\s-\s') 
                            return(
                                document('')/*/config/replacement[find[.=$token]]/replace,             
                                $token
                            )[1]" 
                    separator=" - "
                />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
    <config>
       <replacement>
            <find>Satur</find>
            <replace>Saturday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Sun</find>
            <replace>Sunday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Mon</find>
            <replace>Monday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Tues</find>
            <replace>Tuesday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Wednes</find>
            <replace>Wednesday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Thurs</find>
            <replace>Thursday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Fri</find>
            <replace>Friday</replace>
        </replacement>
    </config>
```

**what is wrong in my codes ?**

Comment: You mention that it doesn't work, but haven't told us what it's doing that doesn't match your expectations. Is it giving an error?

Comment: If you are attempting to execute the transform by loading the XML in a browser, it will not work.  Browsers do not support XSLT 2.0

Comment: Since you moved the config element out of the XSLT and into the source XML, you. Need to adjust the XPath to remove"document('')/*".

Answer (score 3):

**I. XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) solution**:

**Use the following XPath 2.0 one-liner**:

```
concat(replace(.,'\s+-\s*', 'day - '), 'day')
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:sequence select="concat(replace(.,'\s+-\s*', 'day - '), 'day')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>Satur - Sun - Mon - Tues - Wednes - Thurs - Fri</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Saturday - Sunday - Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
       <xsl:with-param name="pS" select=
       "concat(normalize-space(translate(., '-', ' ')), 'day')"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pS"/>
  <xsl:param name="pTarget" select="' '"/>
  <xsl:param name="pReplacement" select="'day - '"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pS">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pS,$pTarget), $pTarget)"/>
   <xsl:if test="contains($pS, $pTarget)">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:call-template name="replace">
     <xsl:with-param name="pS" select="substring-after($pS, $pTarget)"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pTarget" select="$pTarget"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="$pReplacement"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Saturday - Sunday - Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday
```

Comment: it works ..  
but, you only added `day word` to the end of the `replacement word`  
to make `Satur` be `Saturday`  
but, **what about the days in french language ????**  
thank you for your code and your help, but it not the solution that i need ..  
**+1**

Comment: @al-dr,This is a complete and correct answer to your question - the way it is defined in its current form. Please, either update the question, or even better, ask a new question. People shouldn't have to guess what you haven't specified.

Answer (score 2):

**An XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:my="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502665/xsl-how-to-translate-or-replace-string">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="string">Satur - Sun - Mon - Tues - Wednes - Thurs - Fri</xsl:variable>

    <my:config>
        <replacement>
            <find>Satur</find>
            <replace>Saturday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Sun</find>
            <replace>Sunday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Mon</find>
            <replace>Monday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Tues</find>
            <replace>Tuesday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Wednes</find>
            <replace>Wednesday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Thurs</find>
            <replace>Thursday</replace>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <find>Fri</find>
            <replace>Friday</replace>
        </replacement>
    </my:config>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of 
              select="for $token in tokenize($string, '\s-\s') 
                        return
                         (
                          document('')/*/my:config/replacement[find[.=$token]]/replace,             
                          $token
                         )[1]" 
              separator=" - " />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i am newbie in `xsl` and `xml` and i tried your code but it not works  
`100%` it is wrong  
**i will put my codes here**  
**my xsl file:**

Answer (score 2):

A variant on @Mads' answer:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of 
     select="for $token in tokenize($string, '\s-\s') 
        return concat($token, 'day')"
     separator=" - " />
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can omit the `<my:config>`.

Comment: @al-dr: Replace Mads' template with the above template, remove the whole `<my:config>` block, and leave everything else the same. However, if you need days in French, or in multiple languages, then use Mads' solution, not this one.